# Regular expression to split strings between colon(:)

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like `<str1:str2:str3:str4:str5:;`

I want to group these strings as $1,$2,$3,$4,$5.And in this inputs,Strings may come or may not come.If any string is not come then we have to take empty for a group.And in the end we may receive more than one column.

I have tried below code.Any inputs please

```
<filter regexp='s/^\s*&lt;([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):*;.*$/keep_it_method_name $1 aid $2 ctag $3 General_block $4 Data_block $5/'/>
```

Comment: Did you consider String.split(":")?

Comment: Does your string really start with a less-than symbol and end with a colon and a semicolon?

Comment: I can not not use java here.We are using tool developed by internal team.We have to specify this regular expression as part of one of the attributes of xml elements.Like below.<filter regexp='s/^\s*&lt;([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):?([\s\-A-Z_0-9,]*):*;.*$/keep_it_method_name $1 aid $2 ctag $3 General_block $4 Data_block $5/'/>

Comment: yes,my string start with < and ends with ; and after semicolon we get few charcters also

Comment: If you can't use Java, why did you tag with _java_? Can you use Perl, or did you tag with _perl_ because it's a pcre regex? In that case, please [edit] your question, remove _java_ and _perl_ and add _pcre_. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are always five colons in the string, I suggest you do something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = '<str1:str2:str3:str4:str5:;';

my $re = '([^<>:;]*):' x 5;
$re = qr/<$re;/;

if ( $s =~ $re ) {
    no strict 'refs';
    say ${$_} for 1 .. 5;
}
```

#### output

```
str1
str2
str3
str4
str5
```